# How convert $group operator mongodb on spring mongodb

Tags: spring, mongodb

I have an aggregation on Mongodb with:

```
db.exercise.aggregate([
            {$match : {"tags.label" : "shoot"}},
            {$sample : {size : 20}},
            {$group : {_id : null, exercise : {$push : "$$ROOT"}}},
....]
```

I tried to transform it into spring but the $group is always complaining:

```
GroupOperation group = Aggregation.group("exercise").push("$$ROOT").as("exercise");

GroupOperation group = Aggregation.group(_id).push("$$ROOT").as("exercise");

AggregationOperation group = new AggregationOperation() {

            @Override
            public DBObject toDBObject(AggregationOperationContext context) {
                // {$group : {_id : null, exercise : {$push : "$$ROOT"}}},
                return new BasicDBObject("$group", new BasicDBObject(ImmutableMap.<String, Object>builder().
                        put("_id", null).
                        put("exercise", new BasicDBObject("$push", "$$ROOT")).
                        build()));
            }
        };
```

Error messages:

```
No property exercise found for type Exercise!
java.lang.NullPointerException: null value in entry: _id=null
```

Comment: complaining about what

Comment: Try `GroupOperation group = Aggregation.group().push("$$ROOT").as("exercise");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for the mongo query you specified.

```
 MatchOperation matchOperation = match(Criteria.where("tags.label").is("short"));
 LimitOperation limitOperation = limit(20);
 GroupOperation groupOperation = group("_id").push("$$ROOT").as("exercise");

 Aggregation aggregation = newAggregation(matchOperation, limitOperation, groupOperation);
```

Comment: with group("_id") it says: "No property _id found for type Exercise! Did you mean 'id'?" but using .group() such as @Veeram said, it works like a charm.

Comment: It depends. do you have the field _id in exercise document? also as Veeram suggested without and field in group is also fine